# AngularJS - Set selected value from model

Tags: javascript, angularjs

> Angular version - 1.2.28 (Legacy, pending upgrade)

I'm trying to set the selected value for my select element via the model value.

In my Controller I have the below line;

```
$scope.customer.country = 'GB';
```

And in my view I have the below select element;

```
<select
    ng-model="customer.country"
    ng-options="country as country.name for country in countries track by country.alpha2">
</select>
```

I was expecting, that should I have an object in countries with the `alpha2` value of 'GB', it would be selected by default on render.

However the actual behaviour is the empty option is selected by default.

How do I set the default selected value via the model (`ng-model`) value?

Comment: I thought you have rebind the dropdown after initialize the object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems initialization is wrong

```
$scope.customer.country = 'GB';
```

You have to initialize with the same object of array which is binded (**countries**)

should look like

```
$scope.customer.country = $scope.countries[0];
```

[CodePen](http://codepen.io/mastersmind/pen/mmMvmB)